# Is there any formula to select the column dynamically in the below case?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Refer the worksheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1g3mthqijmB7lySfKUvt2NjYT-zVA5oyXr1hJKcJZkdc - Feel fee to edit.
I'm currently trying to get data from a specific column each time the data validation is changed.. It should pull the Names corresponding to FALSE values.. Currently I'm achieving this using multiple IF functions.. If there is a way to directly match the validation input to the row header and then get the values, it would be super great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my duplicate sheet ("Erik Help"):

`=FILTER(E2:E,FILTER(F2:J,F1:J1=B2)=FALSE)`

In plain English, this reads as follows: "Return any names in Column E where the header in in Columns F to J matches the value in cell B2 and where the corresponding value for the name is FALSE."

This formula is written flexibly, assuming that you will have more than two names in Column E within your real sheet. If there are more columns, just extend both instances of `J` to match the new rightmost column.